# Chrome extension to send any Stack Exchange question+answers to your Kindle

Tags: app

I wanted a way to read all the awesome and descriptive answers on Stack Overflow, but I never felt comfortable reading on my monitor. I figured if I could send it to
my [Kindle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Kindle), I can read it at my leisure.

Knowing there'd be others like me, I'm sharing this. [Get it from the webstore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/odpbabpapkjbkcjbcdgeicbmfomiknll).

Please note that this is still beta and it's my first time doing something with
the Stack Exchange API and the Kindle. I am looking forward to your feedback and
suggestions.

Some additional detail, I do not send a `.pdf` file to your kindle address because reading PDFs on the kindle is not very pleasant. Instead, I build a `.mobi` file, which is native to the kindle, so you can treat it like any other kindle book (meaning you can lookup definitions, highlight and make notes).

Here's a picture of this very post (Kindle touch, landscape mode)

[image]

Comment: very cool! will have to check that out

Comment: Oh thank you! With no comments for 12hrs, I was beginning to wonder if I did something wrong :)

Comment: hahah - are you emailing a PDF version of the question to the kindle's email address?

Comment: No, I don't like reading PDF's on the kindle. I actually make a neat html page with the content and then convert it into a native `.mobi` file using kindlegen. I'll add this to the post :)